# Unable to find log4j jar parent dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, log4j, maven-3

I am using Maven 3.6.0 and I have Spring Boot Maven project whose pom file as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>  
    <artifactId>myAppName</artifactId> 
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>    

    <parent>   
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>   
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    
       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.1.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        
         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        
         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency> 
            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
                        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
            
        
            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId> 
          <artifactId>california-theme</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>SadadMC</groupId> 
          <artifactId>SadadMC</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>Jace</groupId> 
          <artifactId>Jace</artifactId> 
          <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>stax-api</groupId> 
          <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId> 
          <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>xlxpScanner</groupId> 
          <artifactId>xlxpScanner</artifactId> 
          <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>xlxpScannerUtils</groupId> 
          <artifactId>xlxpScannerUtils</artifactId> 
          <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <finalName>myAppName</finalName>    
        <plugins>
            
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>          
               <configuration>
                  <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</argLine>
                  <skipTests>true</skipTests>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                                <include>**/*.css</include>
                                <include>**/*.html</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/lib</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.jar</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <!--  <outputDirectory>C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps</outputDirectory> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
         
    </build>
    
    

    <repositories>
    
       <repository>
            <id>java-net-repo</id>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
        
       <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>Central Repository</name>
          <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        
        <repository>
            <id>itext-releases</id>
            <name>iText Repository - releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases</url>
          </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Enonic</id>
            <name>Enonic</name>
            <url>https://repo.enonic.com/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>central-repo</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>       
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>  
        </repository>
        


    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

For some reason I found in my lib folder the following jar **log4j-1.2.14.jar**. I want to exclude this jar from my final war, so I tried **mvn dependency:tree** but I couldn't find the parent dependency.

Also I tried to open **Dependency Hierarchy** from Eclipse but also I couldn't find this jar. How can I exclude this jar?

Comment: Judging from your confriguration your project has a `lib` directory and the content of that directory is copied to `WEB-INF/lib`. Not sure why you would do that, but that is probably where the jar lives

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was really the issue, it's an old project and i didn't thought that the issue might come from there, can you please post this comment as an answer so that i can mark it a correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dependency that has another dependency that has the scope `provided` won't lead to that `provided` dependency being on the classpath. It probably is there because it is needed for testing or building.

So what you should do is check your end deployment unit (your own jar/war) and check if the jar is there in the `lib` directory. If it is something else is managing/including that dependency. (You can use `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out which one).

For more information on the Maven scopes, check [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope). How to include a certain version of Log4j2 (when you are using it) with Spring Boot is described in [this Spring.io blog-post](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot).